# Expo Bare Workflow: OTA updates are no longer forced?

Tags: react-native, expo

I recently ejected my Expo Managed workflow app to use the Bare workflow.

In the past, with the Manaaged workflow when I ran `expo publish`, it would stay on the splash screen and download the update and load the newest version of the app.

However, now I'm noticing that my app downloaded the new version in the background and it moves on from the splash screen a lot more quickly. I even uninstalled the app and downloaded a fresh copy to see if it would have my latest changes.

Is there a way to force the app to download the newest version in the bare workflow?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.expo.io/guides/configuring-ota-updates/#automatic-updates

Second paragraph should be what you are looking for:

> You can also set a nonzero timeout, in which case Expo will attempt to download a new update before launching the app. If there is no network connection available, or it has not finished downloading in the allotted time, Expo will fall back to loading a cached version of your app, and continue trying to fetch the update in the background (at which point it will be saved into the cache for the next app load).